# Azure service health ARM template how to select ALL locations

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I would like to create a template for Service health alert, so its across all services at all regions.

the conditions I have is

```
"condition": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "category",
          "equals": "ServiceHealth",
          "containsAny": null
        },
        {
          "field": "properties.impactedServices[*].ImpactedRegions[*].RegionName",
          "equals": null,
          "containsAny": [
          ]
           }
      ]
    },
```

What should I put under "properties.impactedServices[*].ImpactedRegions[*].RegionName" so it ticks all regions?

Comment: You need to pass the region names

Comment: thanks for that, I know that I need to pass region names.I can do individually like Australia east, US west .but is there a way to pass all region names?

Comment: No , i dont think there is a way

Comment: so does that mean we need to pass in all 41 regions there? what if MS has a new region, we need to add in manually?